# Istio AuthorizationPolicy Support URL-Formatted Claim

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, authorization, istio

I am trying to write an Istio `AuthorizationPolicy` that checks a custom claim that we insert into the JWT. This claim is formatted like `{"https://example.com/example": ["example_1", "example_2"]}`. I've tried writing an `AuthorizationPolicy` like:

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: example
spec:
  action: DENY
  rules:
  - to:
    - operation:
        hosts:
        - myhost.example.com
        paths:
        - /example/path*
    when:
    - key: request.auth.claims[https://example.com/example]
      notValues:
      - example_1
```

but the policy always rejects requests, even when the request's token has `{"https://example.com/example": ["example_1", "example_2"]}` which I would expect to be allowed through. The issue seems to be with the `key: request.auth.claims[https://example.com/example]` line. I suspect that the `:` and `/` characters are causing an issue but I was unable to find any references to that in the Istio documentation. I tried various combinations of escape characters and removing the `https://` but the issue still persists. The policy also worked as expected when checking a different claim with the value in its value list, like

```yaml
when:
- key: request.auth.claims[aud]
  notValues:
  - example_1
```

where `{"aud": ["example_1"]}`.

Is this a limitation of Istio, or is there a way to get this to work that I'm missing? We'd prefer not to refactor how we format our custom claims for now, but can do so if there's no way around it.